# Set SpreadsheetGear workBookSet to an already open excel file

Tags: c#, excel, spreadsheetgear

I am trying to use SpreadsheetGear to access an excel file that is downloaded and opened from a website. I haven't been able to find a way to set an already open and active excel file to a SpreadsheetGear workbook. Saving and then opening from memory is not an option in this circumstance.
I have been using this code to access the application before I started working with SpreadsheetGear:

```
    xl.Application excelApp = (xl.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
```

However, none of the interfaces I've found for spreadsheetGear are compatible with that variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with SpreadsheetGear for .NET, as it does not interact with Microsoft Excel in any way (it's a totally separate product, built from the ground up using only the .NET Framework and has no dependencies on Microsoft Excel).

To open a file in SpreadsheetGear, you'll need to use one of the following methods to do so...

- SpreadsheetGear.Factory.[GetWorbook](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012~SpreadsheetGear.Factory~GetWorkbook.html)(*pathToFile*)
- SpreadsheetGear.IWorkbooks.[Open](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012~SpreadsheetGear.IWorkbooks~Open.html)(*pathToFile*) / [OpenFromMemory](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012~SpreadsheetGear.IWorkbooks~OpenFromMemory.html)(*byteArray*) / [OpenFromStream](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012~SpreadsheetGear.IWorkbooks~OpenFromStream.html)(*streamObj*)

...which means you'll need to save the file from Excel first.